# How to refactor a bash script for running two instances of angular

Tags: bash

I'm running two separate angular proyects at the same time, so in an effort to get things working faster I made two bash script like this:

script1:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    cd /somefolder/proyect1
    ng serve
```

and script2:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    cd /somefolder/proyect2
    ng serve --port 5000
```

After that I make them executable with "chmod +x script1" and "chmod +x script2".

And then I made the final script:

final_script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    ./script1 & ./script2 && fg
```

Then "chmod +x final_script" and voila! everithing works as expected.

The thing is I feel like I'm reapeating myself here, is there a way to merge both script into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply try :

final_script

```
(cd /somefolder/proyect1; ng serve) & (cd /somefolder/proyect1; ng serve --port 5000) && fg
```

Or use Angular CLI that supports now [multi-apps integration](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps).

Comment: I tried that with no success, now I see that I had an extra semi-colon after both ng serve. I'll check the multiapp support for sure!

Comment: @Gusdc shell syntax can be confusing. You'd need a final semicolon inside `{ }`, but not in `( )`. It might be more intuitive (& readable) to break it into multiple lines, with the close parentheses on separate lines; the line breaks can be used in place of semicolons, but extra ones (like before the close parenthesis) won't cause syntax errors.